# Filtering a list of monads

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to filter a list of type: `IO [Either a b]`

Ideally, I would like to compose filtering function with the following type sig:

```
(Monad m, Monad m2) => m [m2 a] -> (a -> Bool) -> m [m2 a]
```

I have tried a lot of combinations of `filter`, `filterM`, `fmap`, and `=<<` in a vain attempt to lift my predicate into the proper context, but I keep missing the mark - I can achieve `m [m a]-> (a -> m Bool)-> m [m a]`, but since Either and IO are not the same monad, this doesn't seem to do me any good.

This seems like a usecase for 'do notation' , but I've been unable to suss out a way to examine the type signatures of things assigned with the `<-` operator, and so am left shooting at a moving target.

I am not sure how to compose the function in a way that will make it clear that it's traversing a list containing a instances of a different monad (Either) then the monad that contains the list itself (IO).

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can `fmap` the predicate into the `m2` but how do you intend to inspect the resulting `m2 Bool`? The best you can do is `(Functor f, Applicative g) => (a -> Bool) -> f [g a] -> f (g [a])`

Comment: As @BenjaminHodgson points out, you can reach for `Traversable` when you need something of the shape: `t (f a) -> f (t a)`

Comment: I assumed there was some sort of a function for filtering a list of monads of a given type, and that I'd lift that function onto the IO monad.
Like, for example: ` filterM (liftM . (\x->True))`
Can filter a list of monads -

I understand that, internally, concatenating instances of `[Either a b]` is different from concatenating instances of `IO [Either a b]`, and so this won't work, but that's not impossible, it's just a headache.

I assumed I wasn't the first person to have this problem, and that someone else had solved it.

Comment: Note that your outer `m` is not really an interesting part of the question, as you can just `fmap myFilter`, so what you want is really `myFilter :: (Monad m2) => [m2 a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [m2 a]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ideally, I would like to compose filtering function with the following
>   type sig:
>
> ```
> (Monad m, Monad m2) => m [m2 a] -> (a -> Bool) -> m [m2 a]
> ```

It can't be done in general, because the `Monad` interface provides no way to get an `a` out of an `m a`. You can get as far as `m [m2 Bool]` using `fmap (fmap (fmap f))` but you need to get the `Bool` out of the `m2 Bool` in order to decide whether or not to drop the element.

Look at it this way. What if the monad in question was `Proxy`?

```
data Proxy a = Proxy  -- one constructor, no fields

instance Monad Proxy where
    return _ = Proxy
    Proxy >>= _ = Proxy
```

You can't look at the `Bool` inside a `Proxy Bool` because there's never anything inside it! Given `a -> Bool` and `[Proxy a]`, how can I be expected to know which elements of the list to drop?

---

You *can* write a function with the following type signature:

```
myfilter :: (Functor f, Applicative g) => (a -> Bool) -> f [g a] -> f (g [a])
```

Note that the return type is `f (g [a])`, not `f [g a]`.

This function uses `fmap` to go into the outer functor, smashes together the applicative `g`s in the list, then `fmap`s once more to filter the results.

```
myfilter p = fmap (fmap (filter p) . sequenceA)
```

Comment: This works, thank you!

I am not sure I quite understand though -

If you "can't get the Bool out of it's wrapper", how would filtering anything of type [m a] work at all?
-EDIT-
More clearly -

If ` fmap (map (fmap (*3))) (Just ([Right 5, Right 12]))`
returns `Just [Right 15, Right 36]`
Why can't there be a filter that does the same thing?

Comment: In general you don't work with monads by getting things out of them; instead you lift yourself into the monad. You can't get the `a` out of the `[m a]`, but you can push the `[]` inside the `m` using `sequenceA :: Applicative m => [m a] -> m [a]`. If `m` is `Proxy` then you have `sequenceA :: [Proxy a] -> Proxy a; sequenceA _ = Proxy`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer while you may not be able to get the `a` out of the `Monad m`, you can get your functions into the `Monad m` using e.g. `liftM`. Depending on the inner structure(s) you can still compose usable actions and then finally sequence them in some fashion so the computations 'happen' in the desired fashion.

To give an example using the problem of `IO[Either a b]` given as `IO[Either Bool Integer]`:

```
import Control.Monad

testCase :: IO [Either Bool Integer]
testCase = return [(Right 1), (Left True), (Right 2), (Left False), (Right 3), (Right 4)]

liftFilter :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> m [a] -> m [a]
liftFilter pred = liftM (filter pred)

testFilter :: (Either Bool Integer) -> Bool
testFilter (Left True) = True
testFilter (Right x)   = even x
testFilter _           = False

showIt :: (Either Bool Integer) -> String
showIt (Left True)  = "Left True"
showIt (Left False) = "Left False"
showIt (Right x)    = "Right x=" ++ (show x)

test = do
    filtered <- liftFilter testFilter testCase
    return (fmap showIt filtered)

runTest = do
    actions <- liftM (fmap putStrLn) test
    sequence_ actions
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a very helpful addendum.

Answer (score 0):

I am handling the lists using their monad instance instead of using filter method. It may be better to use the filter in real world situations. I'm also not trying to make my functions as small as possible

I assumed you want some arbitrary method to handle the Eithers.
If you want to only filter the "right a" or get the left then you probably should use traversable. You also could use bimap to "fmap" left and right of Either simultaneously.

First a solution that works only with `either`:

```
filtermonads :: IO [(Either a b)] -> (a -> Bool) -> IO [(Either a b)]
filtermonads ioListEitherA cond = do
  listEitherA <- ioListEitherA
  return $ do
        eitherA <- listEitherA
        case eitherA of
          Left a -> if cond a then pure (Left a) else []
          Right b -> return (Right b)
```

Should be the same as the following:

```
filtermonads' :: IO [(Either a b)] -> (a -> Bool) -> IO [(Either a b)]
filtermonads' ioListEitherA cond = let
  f x = case x of
    Left a -> if cond a then pure (Left a) else []
    Right a -> pure (Right a)
  in
    fmap (join . fmap f) ioListEitherA
```

We have to manually open the Either as we require access to the information encapsulated inside it in order to know how to handle the list.

You could generalize this by instead separately providing a function (`m2 a -> Bool`) that tells how to extract the information from the monad.

```
eitherCond :: Either a b -> Bool
eitherCond eitherA = case eitherA of
          Left a -> False
          Right b -> True

filtermonads'' :: (Monad m) => m [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> m [a]
filtermonads'' m1listm2a cond = do
  listm2a <- m1listm2a
  return $ do
    m2a <- listm2a
    if cond m2a then pure m2a else []
```

You could also generalize the list to `MonadPlus` or `MonadFail` as you can think of filtering meaning you need a monad with a zero element. The monad library itself also has fail that is sometimes zero, but you should not use it as it is not a feature all plain monads have and as such the implementations are sometimes very arbitrary.

Plain filter might be better as only few structures implement the `MonadPlus` class. I should have used `mfilter` for this. `MonadPlus` also doesn't have that many structures that implement it. For example Map is not even a monad.

```
filtermonads''' :: (Monad m1, MonadPlus mp) => m1 (mp a) -> (a -> Bool) -> m1 (mp a)
filtermonads''' m1listm2a cond = do
  listm2a <- m1listm2a
  return $ do
    m2a <- listm2a
    if cond m2a then pure m2a else mzero
```

```
testData :: IO [Either Char Char]
testData = pure [Right 'a', Left 'a', Left 'c']

test1 = filtermonads testData (\x -> x=='a')
test2 = filtermonads' testData (\x -> x=='a')
test3 = filtermonads'' testData eitherCond
test4 = filtermonads''' testData eitherCond

justData ::IO (Maybe Char)
justData = pure (Just 'b')
readData :: Maybe (IO Char)
readData = Just (getChar) -- Notice that io mzero is error!
test5 = filtermonads''' justData (\x -> x=='a')
test6 = filtermonads''' readData (\x -> x=='a') 
main = case (test6) of
  Just a -> a >>= putStrLn . pure
  Nothing -> pure ()
```